# List of object and string as a key in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a key which is a list of an object and a string. Example: [Obj, "test"]. I want to convert this into a key for a dictionary in python -> {[Obj, "test"]: value}

I have seen that you could convert the list into a string and use that as a key: key = "[Obj, 'test']". But the problem with that is that I cannot access the methods for Obj.

Is there a way to achieve this while conserving the Object's properties?

Comment: The keys of a dictionary need to be hashable. A list is not hashable, but a tuple is. If you use a tuple you will be able to do what you intend. However, I really do not think that this is the best way to do what you want to do.

Comment: @Shrinra tensei Thank You! It works. Can you please suggest an alternate way that might be better?

Comment: Well, the keys in a dictionary should generally be strings (not that you can't do otherwise, but it's the best in terms of simplicity and efficiency). If your objects have some kind of id, use it as the key. Otherwise maybe you should create such key, it's very easy to create a random one with the `uuid` module.